# Flutter app deeplink opens android app but can not open ios app

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

My problem is this;

I am trying to implement a deeplink feature to my flutter app. I followed the steps on the official docs https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links
and the android app is opening but the ios app is not opening via a link.

I added the deeplink property to info.plist file.
[image]

I also add the associated domains capability with developer mode.

[image]

I also checked the accessibility of the `apple-app-site-association` file with https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
[image]

Until now everything seems to be okey but when I try to open the app with deeplink

`xcrun simctl openurl booted https://<my-domain>/login_screen`,

the application do not open and sends me to a web page saying that it couldn't find a page with that path.

[image]

I have been searching for a fix but couldn't find any. I am not sure whether am I missing a point or not. Any idea what may cause this behavior and how can I fix this situation?

**Update 1:** I found a link to test the CDN which is;

```
https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<my-domain>
```

But this returns me only a text saying **Not Found**. This probably means that the CDN can not reach my AASA file. However, `Branch.io` AASA validator says that my file is okey. I can also see the file when I enter the url `https://<my-domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. Still no solution.

**Update:2** I found something on the internet that helps people see what's happening when they try to enter a link. The thing I found is this;

```
curl -v https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/<my-domain>
```

When you enter this code into the terminal, it provides a verbose output of the actions that occur while attempting to enter the URL we provided. Here is my terminal log when I enter the code into the terminal;

```
* Connected to app-site-association.cdn-apple.com (17.253.107.201) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; O=Apple Inc.; CN=app-site-association.cdn-apple.com
*  start date: Sep 29 18:10:48 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 28 18:20:48 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "app-site-association.cdn-apple.com" matched cert's "app-site-association.cdn-apple.com"
*  issuer: CN=Apple Public Server ECC CA 12 - G1; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET /a/v1/<my-domain> HTTP/1.1
> Host: app-site-association.cdn-apple.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Apple-Failure-Details: {"cause":"local error: tls: no renegotiation"}
< Apple-Failure-Reason: SWCERR00303 TLS error
< Apple-From: https://<my-domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
< Apple-Try-Direct: false
< Cache-Control: max-age=3600,public
< Content-Length: 10
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Mon, 02 Oct 2023 08:25:18 GMT
< Age: 5
< Via: https/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pst-004.ts.apple.com (acdn/4.1), https/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pac-004.ts.apple.com (acdn/4.1), https/1.1 dkvib1-3p-pfe-014.ts.apple.com (acdn/4.1), https/1.1 dkblp1-edge-lx-008.ts.apple.com (acdn/4.1), https/1.1 dkblp1-edge-bx-007.ts.apple.com (acdn/4.1)
< X-Cache: hit-stale, miss, miss, miss, miss
< CDNUUID: 94a11630-9b2a-4bd9-b1cb-a26474607b0a-199948940
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
Not Found
* Connection #0 to host app-site-association.cdn-apple.com left intact
```

So what does this mean? Is my webserver's configuration problematic or the Apple's connectivity protocols are different. I do not understand. Still no solution.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnasAyub no I did not.

Comment: i solved my problem by removing www. from my domain in Xcode

Comment: @AnasAyub Thanks for your response but I never add the "www" to Xcode.